# Disabling Random-MAC permanetly on Samsung

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

Hello Stackoverflow Communitie,

does anyone know how to disable the random-mac permanetly. I know where to set the tablet mac and I only can find instructions how to do that, but after a reboot of the tablet I have to change the mac-adress again.

Thank you for your time and help. If there is a better place to ask this questions please tell me.

Comment: You should be able to disable the randomized MAC address on a per-Wifi base. Check the setting of each configured Wifi network and disable the privacy feature.

Comment: Hallo Robert, if u mean I have to set tablet-mac than your awnser won't help me, because it returns to random mac after a restart and I need it to stay on tablet-mac because else my device will not get an ip-adress. If u meant I have to disable a setting called privacy feature in the Wifi configuration, than could u please give me a bit more detail, because I can not find it.

Comment: So you are faking your MAC address, that has nothing to do with random/privacy MAC. That is never applied permanently.

Comment: I want to use my device mac address like I said but after a reboot the random MAC is automatically used. I want to know if there is a way to use my tablet mac, but I guess it isnt possible, because I couldnt find any website that describes this process. You just gave me the same awnser as I already found like I explained in my original post I know how to change the random-mac to the tablet mac but I want it to be permanent. I never said anything about faking my MAC address.

Comment: As I wrote in modern Android versions you can disable the privacy MAC for each known Wifi network individually. Also the MAC is not random, for the same Wifi it should always be the same, only for different Wifis different MAC addresses are generated. Please read https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-mac-randomization BTW: Stackoberflow.com is the wrong place for such a question, this suits better https://android.stackexchange.com Unfortunately this site is not a migration target here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question is not a bout programming. It should better be posted on https://android.stackexchange.com (if somebody knows how to migrate a question from SO directly to that site please contact me, I don't get that site as migration target).

Comment: Like i said ur no help, ur not understanding what I am asking apperently. In my original post I asked where to post it but until ur second newest command u did not give me the awnser. Still thank u for your help and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to change the random MAC to the tablet MAC permanently. After a reboot of your tablet you have to repeat the process of changing the random MAC to the tablet MAC.

The following Websites are my sources:
https://wifi-helpcenter.nokia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056890733-Issues-with-random-MAC-addresses-Android-10-iOS-14-
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-mac-randomization

How to change random MAC to Tablet MAC:
https://www.easytechguides.com/disable-device-security-on-a-samsung-galaxy/
After a reboot you have to repeat the process.